# How to make a manually scrollable marquee (by touch or mouse/touchpad scroll) in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I often want to quickly read all of a long text like a long song name in YouTube music without waiting for the slow auto-marquee, or a long text/title ellipsized in a list.

Until this arrives, I'd like to know how I could give that UX improvement with Jetpack Compose on Android (though I'm also interested in other platforms).

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use a `ScrollableRow` to scroll your text horizontally

```
@Composable
fun ScrollableRowDemo() {
    ScrollableRow(children = {
        Row {
            Text(
                text = "This is my long long long long long text that I want to scroll horizontally",
                style = (MaterialTheme.typography).body1
            )
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This does not address Louis' interest in having it automatically scroll slowly, in addition to the user being able to manually scroll more quickly.

Comment: Sorry @CommonsWare , I tought he needed to explicitly scroll horizontally the text on touch